# How to create condition for warnings in R

Tags: r, for-loop, warnings

I am trying to create a "for" loop where each of 100 trials has a set of parameters, each randomly chosen from probability distributions. From there, a model will take in these parameters and spit out an output. The input and output will be stored in a matrix, with each row representing a successful run through. Eventually, this matrix will be converted into a dataframe. I am displaying a sample run through for one case of the for loop below:

```
#matrix M will have 100 rows for each trial, and 4 columns
#columns will be a val, b val, c val and output
M <- matrix(0, nrow=100, ncol=4)

for (i in 1:100){
#random values for a,b,c for 1st trial
a =runif(1)
b=runif(1)
c=runif (1)
v <- c(a,b,c)
#some model
output[i]=v[1]*v[2]/v[3]
M[i,4]=output[i]
#don't know how to populate first 3 columns with all diff values of a,b,c
}
```

I know this code will not work, but that's my first question. How do I get the a,b, and c values to regenerate from trial to trial so I can have new outputs for each trial. From there, I am pretty sure I know how to store them in the matrix.

My last question is about warning messages. If I have a warning message because my output did not generate for some trial (no problems with this one, but if I had to divide by 0 or something)... how could I just tell the program to skip that trial and keep going until we get to 100 working trials?

Please comment if I should edit or clarify something above. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your first question, you can first generate parameter vectors and then apply your function to each parameter set.

```
ntrials <- 100
M <- matrix(0, nrow=ntrials, ncol=4)

## Generate parameter vectors
M[,1] <- runif(ntrials)
M[,2] <- runif(ntrials)
M[,3] <- runif(ntrials)

## Example model function
run_mod <- function(a, b, c) {

    return(a+b+c)

}

## Create output
M[, 4] <- run_mod(a = M[, 1], b = M[, 2], c = M[, 3])
```

To address your second question, you could use a `while` statement to continue generating parameter sets and trying to obtain valid model results until you have enough valid results. Your model function will need a way to handle errors or warnings that could occur, such as `tryCatch()`.

```
## Example model function with error handling
run_mod <- function(a, b, c) {

    tryCatch(

        a+b+c,
        error = function(e) print("Error"),
        warning = function(w) print("Warning")
    )

    return(a+b+c)

}

i <- 0
while(i < ntrials) {
  
  ## Generate a single set of parameters
  a <- runif(1)
  b <- runif(1)
  c <- runif(1)
  
  ## Example error
  if(floor(100*a) %% 2 == 0) {
    
    a <- "Bad parameter"
    
  }
  
  ## Try running your model
  output <- run_mod(a,b,c)
  
  ## If successful, save output and move on to the next set
  if(!is.character(output)) {
    
    M[i, 1] <- a
    M[i, 2] <- b
    M[i, 3] <- c
    M[i, 4] <- output
    i <- i + 1
    
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much! I will try in a bit and then approve